# Это по-русски правильно? Можно перебежать?

Tags: лексика

На уроке физкультуры можно ли сказать: "Можно перебежать?" в смысле пересдать зачёт по бегу. Это по-русски правильно?

Answer (score 6):

Это из области спортивного жаргона, встречается в спортивной журналистике и даже в некоторых книгах (т. е., в соотв. контексте пропускается корректорами). Например, так писали об известном эпизоде с повторным забегом в олимпийской эстафете сборной США; в отдельных источниках это слово тактично брали в *кавычки* - с пониманием того, что пишут для широкой аудитории и что для обычной речи это ***ненормативно***. 
Пример из книги:

*Яремчук Е. "Бег для всех. Доступная программа тренировок." изд. Питер 2015, c.93*

> Таких спортсменов дисквалифицируют, а пострадавшим дают *перебежать
>   дистанцию*, если это возможно.

В разговоре с преподавателем физкультуры такое допустимо, поскольку ему это будет понятно (заново пробежать дистанцию для повторной сдачи зачёта) и в этом нет особой фамильярности.

Answer (score 1):

*Пересдать зачёт по бегу* -- правильно. Перебежать можно дорогу, а вот *перебежать* в смысле *пересдать зачёт по бегу* -- **неправильно**.